# static position and orientation sensing

Tags: position

I have an application to sense magnetic north and position. GPS works well for position but cannot determine orientation without spinning the object 3 times.
My application is stationary and I cannot spin anything.
Is there a magnetic sensor that can detect the earth's magnetic north pole?
Thanks,
Stu

Comment: There is no shortage of magnetometers on the market.

Answer (score 2):

A single GPS receiver by itself cannot determine orientation under any circumstances.

I don't know where you got the "spinning the object 3 times", but that sounds more like the calibration procedure for a magnetometer.

There are plenty of 2D and 3D magnetometers available, as well as "9 DOF" sensors that integrate accelerometers, rate gyros and magnetometers into a single package.

Comment: Dave is correct. GPS determine a location. To use them for direction multiple samples are taken whilst moving and the direction is inferred from the change in position.